# can't parse JSON File

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to Parse this JSON-File but I get an error which I understand but don't know how to find a way around it

```
JSONArray locations = new JSONArray(jsonString);
```

Error

```
Json parsing error: Value [{"lon":8.6520691,"type":"fuel","address":"Frankfurter Straße 65","lat":49.8848387,"name":"Esso"},{
.."lon":8.6419863,"type":"fuel","address":"Rüdesheimer Straße 114","lat":49.8540121,"name":"Aral Tankstelle"},{"lon":8.6468131,"type":"fuel","address":"Heidelberger Straße 55-59","lat":49.8614199,"name":"Total"},{"lon":8.6311635,"type":"fuel","address":"Pallaswiesenviertel Pallaswiesenstraße","lat":49.8847555,"name":"Firma Karaahmetaglu"},{"lon":8.6429677,"type":"fuel","address":"Pallaswiesenstraße 85","lat":49.8825735,"name":"Shell"},{"lon":8.6443997,"type":"fuel","address":"Johannesviertel Kasinostraße","lat":49.8796515,"name":"Jet"},{"capacity":90,"lon":8.647085,"type":"pub","address":"Mollerstadt Saalbaustraße","lat":49.8714409,"name":"Unikum"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Changed

```
if(c.has("icon"){
icon = c.getString("icon");
}else{
icon = "";
}
```

To

```
if(c.has("icon"){
icon = c.getString("icon");
}else{
icon = "@drawable/seekbarthumb1";
}
```

SOLVED

Comment: Why not generate a POJO representation of the JSON string and then use Gson to parse your result?

Comment: I've edited your post to remove the noise from the logcat, now show the code as a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root-object of a json-file should be an json-object, you can make a tag with the list named `"data"`. Some parsers may allow it but it is not recommended. If you cannot change the file, just parse `"{ \"file\": " + jsonStr + "}"` and use its member file.

**Edit:**

An array as root-object should be supported (you are writing the code, as the root-object is not an array (JSONArray) but an object (JSONObject), but it is an array), strings or numbers are not always supported.
Just change the type parsing the string:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
JSONArray locations = jsonObject.getJSONArray("");
```

to

```
JSONArray locations = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
```

The error occurs in the first line and is yielded by the parser because it expects an object and not an array.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by \"file\"?

Comment: ``"{ \"file\": `` is the start-tag, for a (dirty) solution if your library only supports parsing json with JSONObject. So that you can acces the list itsself by ``jsonObject.getJSONArray("file")``. But the second solution should work better.

Comment: It worked but now the Activity dies during parsing (?)

Edited answer